# Why is variance specifically important?

Tags: variance, reporting

Usually in every statistics summary variance as well as st. deviation are included. Is there a reason why just variance would give a meaningful information, that st. deviation doesn't yield?

Comment: Usually I only see one or the other. Can you give concrete examples?

Comment: If variance and SD refer to the same thing, then SD is just the square root of the variance. So either SD or variance should suffice (but both may be given for convenience).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One or the other of variance and standard deviation is typically more useful in a particular context.

For example, many important statistical formulas are most simply expressed in terms of *variance*:

- The variance of a sum of uncorrelated variables is the [sum of their
  variances](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Sum_of_uncorrelated_variables_(Bienaym%C3%A9_formula)).
- The [F-test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-test) that underlies
  much of statistical inference is based on a ratio of variances.

On the other hand, the units of a *standard deviation* are the same as the original units of the variable. So for things like estimating relative error the standard deviation is more intuitive.